# I receive NULL values when trying to send Ajax jQuery parameters in POST request - MVC CORE

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm a little new to ASP.NET MVC core.

My requirement is the following: I have a `Contact.cshtml` view which contains a contact form.

After the user fills the contact form and clicks the "submit" button, I want to send the entered form parameters to the controller with the Ajax jQuery post method, and then send feedback back to the user without refreshing the page.

My controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Contact(string name, string email, string subject, string message)
{
        // Future code will be entered here and do some logic with the parameters

        // This will be replaced with a call to a partial View which contains a success message
        return View();
}
```

Part of my `Contact.cshtml` file:

```
<form method="post" role="form" id="contactForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">השם שלך</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">כתובת מייל</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="subject">נושא</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="message">הודעה</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="message" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-theme">שלח</button>
</form>

@section scripts
{
            <script>
                    $('#contactForm').submit(function () {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '/Home/Contact',
                            type: 'post',
                            data: { 'name': $('#name').val() },
                            success: function (data) {
                                alert(data);
                            }
                        });
                    });
            </script>
}
```

I have managed to narrow down the problem. Everything is fine in what I've written but the selector for `$('#name').val()` doesn't work. It returns `null` value! If I put some hard coded value like "john doe" instead of the selector then it works! Can someone tell me what the problem with this jQuery selector is? Thanks!

Comment: Well, `$('#message')` is an object containing a DOM node, and `toString` probably just gives you `[object, Object]` for all your values, is that what you're looking for ? You probably wanted `$('#message').val()`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/h1t4kbof/

Comment: I tried val() too.... It didn't work for me my friend

Comment: You also need to stop the form submission using `preventDefault`: `$('#contactForm').submit(function (e) { e.preventDefault(); // your code...`. Your `$.post` call also seems to be missing a URL value, but I assume that was just removed from your example in the question

Comment: Hey Rory, its ok, there is no need for the URL..
I put a break point inside the controller method and it got there.. Perhaps its because I put the [HttpPost] action filter so it knows that it needs to be called

Comment: what does your method signature look like?

Comment: Hey MisterPositive, please have a look again.. I've written it in the top.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work fine. Make sure you are preventing the default normal form submit behavior. You may use jQuery `preventDefault` method to do so.

```
$('#contactForm').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // your existing code
});
```

Also you may consider sending the serialized form to the action method instead of reading the input values one by one.

```
$(function() {
    $('#contactForm').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/Contact',
            type: 'post',
            data: $(this).serialize(),                   
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

You need to make sure your form elements has a `name` attribute which matches with your action method parameter names

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" />
<input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" //>
```